# Accessing Deeply nested HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have this HashMap:

`HashMap<String,HashMap<Float,HashMap<Float,String>>>`

But I'm not to sure how to add and remove elements from the most deeply nest structure.
Can someone give an example?

Thanks :)

Update:

Thanks for the help, But how can I just put on the first level of the HashMap? I have tried .put and I am getting an error.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to provide 3 keys at least.

Comment: `outerHashmap.get(key1).get(key2).put(key3, value);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create the map:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Float,HashMap<Float, String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then put the first level map into it:

```
map.put("one", new HashMap<Float, HashMap<Float, String>>());
```

Then put a HashMap in the last level:

```
map.get("one").put(1.0f,new HashMap<Float, String>());
```

Now put an element in the new map:

```
map.get("one").get(1.0f).put(2.0f,"this is lame");
```

and now it can be gotten as described above:

```
System.out.println(map.get("one").get(1.0f).get(2.0f));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you plan on constructing homogeneous HashMaps *with variable depth*, use a **recursive data structure**.

Below is an implementation providing a sample interface:

```
class NestedMap<K, V> {

    private final HashMap<K, NestedMap> child;
    private V value;

    public NestedMap() {
        child = new HashMap<>();
        value = null;
    }

    public boolean hasChild(K k) {
        return this.child.containsKey(k);
    }

    public NestedMap<K, V> getChild(K k) {
        return this.child.get(k);
    }

    public void makeChild(K k) {
        this.child.put(k, new NestedMap());
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V v) {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

and example usage:

```
class NestedMapIllustration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NestedMap<Character, String> m = new NestedMap<>();

        m.makeChild('f');
        m.getChild('f').makeChild('o');
        m.getChild('f').getChild('o').makeChild('o');
        m.getChild('f').getChild('o').getChild('o').setValue("bar");

        System.out.println(
            "nested element at 'f' -> 'o' -> 'o' is " +
            m.getChild('f').getChild('o').getChild('o').getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having `HashMap<String,HashMap<Float,HashMap<Float,String>>> map` and without accounting for `null` values, just follow the logical sequence that you would formulate in your mind to access the inner map and translate to the following code:

```
map.get(strKey).get(floatKey).put(newFloat, newString);
map.get(strKey).get(floatKey).remove(newFloat);
```

`strKey` is a key `String` in the first-level map

`floatKey` a key `Float` in the second-level map

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look, shall we?

First layer is a `HashMap<String, HashMap>`, so let's `get`.

```
map.get(strKey); // Returns another HashMap
```

We've got another `HashMap` back, so what do we do? We use `get` again!

```
map.get(strKey).get(1.0f); // Returns another HashMap
```

Again, what do we do? Well only one thing for it. `get`!

```
map.get(strKey).get(1.0f).get(1.0f); // Returns a String
```

This is the value in the deeply nested `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

So first you will do a get on the first HashMap with a String as key. It will return you an `HashMap<Float,HashMap<Float,String>>`.

You will then do a get on that HashMap with a Float as key. It will return a `HashMap<Float,String>`.

You will finally do a get on that HashMap with a Float as key and there, you have the String you want.
Same thing with a put instead of get on the last HashMap to insert a value.