# Deeply nested hashmaps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, snakeyaml

I have used this example to 
[Accessing Deeply nested HashMaps in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536599/accessing-deeply-nested-hashmaps-in-java)
build the data structure to store node names and properties.

Here is the updated code:

```
class NestedMap {

private final HashMap<String, NestedMap> child;

private Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();

public NestedMap() {
    child = new HashMap<>();
    setValue(null);
}

public boolean hasChild(String k) {
    return this.child.containsKey(k);
}

public NestedMap getChild(String k) {
    return this.child.get(k);
}

public void makeChild(String k) {
    this.child.put(k, new NestedMap());
}

public Map<String, Object> getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Map<String, Object> value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

And my usage example:

```
    class NestedMapIllustration {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        NestedMap m = new NestedMap();

        m.makeChild("de");
        m.getChild("de").makeChild("content");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").makeChild("00");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").makeChild("0");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").makeChild("1");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").makeChild("01");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").getChild("01").makeChild("fieldsets");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").getChild("01").getChild("fieldsets").makeChild("0");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").getChild("01").getChild("fieldsets").getChild("0").makeChild("fields");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").getChild("01").getChild("fieldsets").getChild("0").getChild("fields").makeChild("0");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("key", "value");
        properties.put("key2", "value");
        m.getChild("de").getChild("content").getChild("01").getChild("fieldsets").getChild("0").getChild("fields").setValue(properties);
}
```

Instead of creating a new object each value I would like to always create a **new HashMap** where I can store the node properties.

I receive my data structure by visiting nodes in the JCR datastore and extracting their values and properties. This is how my resulting data structure should look in the output yaml file:

[image]

How can I do that more efficiently?

Comment: Why not go with an industry standard like JSON instead?

Comment: I believe I need to build a map structure for snakeyaml dump (https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-dumping-yaml).

Comment: You don't need a map structure, it's just used as an example (like `List<Integer>`). If you already have the class structure, you should be able to serialize that directly. Even if you want a specific structure, I'd advise against creating your own mechanism like that.

Comment: I do have class structure but from what I understand I need to store it in an object in memory before I can dump it with snakeyaml.  This is why I was trying to store it in a nested map structure. Sorry, but I do not understand what you meant by serialize it directly?

Comment: I meant that if you have data in that form already, you could dump it without any nested maps. Where does this `de` and `content` and `fieldsets` come from? What's the big idea behind this code?

Comment: `de`, `content`, `00`, `fieldsets` are node names from the JCR datastore. Each nodename has it properties. I need to visit the nodes and dump the name and proeprties for each node I visit using snakeyaml.

Comment: So you don't actually need nested maps, you need to dump some data as YAML. Now you're getting to the root of the problem. I'd recommend reading the snakeyaml documentation to see how you can write the file in parts, you're just wasting your time trying to convert things to maps first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try as you suggested `If you need to dump several YAML documents to a single stream, use the method Yaml.dumpAll(Iterator<Object> data). It accepts an Iterator of Java objects to be serialized into a YAML document`.

Comment: I tried the dumpAll method but unfortunately I loose the hierarchy of the nodes (children parent relationship).  I can preserve that with a nested map structure.  The thing is that I do not know how deep my nested map is until I visit all the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution to the problem using recursion***

```
public HashMap<String,Object> nestedMap(Node node) {

           HashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

           PropertyIterator pi;
            try {
                pi = node.getProperties();
                //Get properties for the root node
                   while(pi.hasNext())
                    {
                       Property p = pi.nextProperty();
                       String name = p.getName();
                       String val = p.getString();

                       map.put(name,val);

                    }//end of while for properties of root node
            } catch (RepositoryException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


           Iterable<Node> children;
            try {
                children = NodeUtil.getNodes(node);
                for (Node child : children) {

                    if (!child.getPrimaryNodeType().getName().contains("mgnl:page")) {  
                      map.put (child.getName(), nestedMap(child));

                   }//end of checking if PrimaryNodeType is of type mgnl:page
                }

            } catch (RepositoryException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return map;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've gone out of your way to let you use any key, but you're using string keys, even though one of the keys is `"01"` which suggests it's a number instead.

Can I conclude from this that keys are always strings?

In that case, why not define a separator, say, the slash, and use a plain old `TreeMap<String, V>`? Then you can do:

```
m.put("de/content/01/fieldsets/0/fields", properties);
```

If you want everything in the `de/content/01` 'tree', you can do:

```
m.subMap("de/content/01/", "de/content/010");
```

The above will give you a map containing every child of de/content/01. The `0` at the end of the `010` there is 'magic': Zero is the next character, after slash, in the ascii table.

If you want any given key to map to any number of values, you can use:

```
TreeMap<String, List<V>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

to put things in:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(elem);
```

and to get things out:

```
for (V value : map.getOrDefault(key, List.of())) {
    // works even if key isn't in there (loops 0 times then)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the key is a string. I updated my code removing the generics like you suggested. I am not sure how to use the TreeMap structure you suggested. I need to preserve the hierarchy of nodes (ie. know who is the parent node).

Comment: The hierarchy is inherent in the sorting: TreeMaps are inherently sorted. That's the trick here. To get to a parent, just scan for the last slash and remove all text until then.